# How to NOT lowercase a text in TextBlob

Tags: python, textblob

I am using the library TextBlob to analyse law texts. I really like TextBlob but I am struggling with some features.  When I create a `TextBlob` object, it automatically lowercases my entire text.

```
from textblob import TextBlob    
text_blob = TextBlob(input_text)
```

This is inconvenient for me because I want to use the Entity Recognition method to find entries in the law texts, and many of them are capitalized (e.g. LEI, ISO, Member State, etc...). I want to leave those as they are, capitalized. Any other way Entity Recognizer won't find all possible entities (or I would have to lowercase everything, which is not my plan).

Is there a way to NOT lowercase the entire text with TextBlob, like passing a parameter:

```
from textblob import TextBlob    
text_blob = TextBlob(input_text, lower=False)
```

I have tried a couple of things but without good results. I haven't found an answer in the documentation of TextBlob either. Maybe it is a very simple task.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for this in TextBlob, I have decided to solved this issue in my case by lowercasing all entries in advanced. I don't think there is another option in TextBlob.

Comment: Ask the project maintenaner question here. 
https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob